# How to block hping3 SYN ACK efficiently with iptables?

Tags: nginx, iptables, attacks, flooding, syn

I'm trying to execute a TCP SYN flood on my Debian web server with nginx.

Executing `tcpdump "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0"` while flooding, I see all packets coming.

`iptables` seem to work well with SYN packets generated from raw socket, but not with `hping3 178.33.123.111 --flood -S -L 0 -p 80` attack.

Please, could you suggest iptables rules to log and drop this attack?